# DataTables not initialising correctly with Bootstrap modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm having two problems with DataTables and Bootstrap modals.

1. **Can't use dynamically built buttons after page 1**

**(Solved by Yuri)**

I have this table, It is built dynamically by an AJAX request, the data loads correctly and builds up the table as it should, the buttons 'Manage' and 'Delete' have classes set on them, when clicked it should open another modal on top of the current one, on the 1st page of the table it works fine, if I go to page 2 it doesn't action anything as if there is no listener on it.

[image]

2. **Datatables not initialising on the 2nd modal (Could be related to issue 1)**

I have the below jQuery to initialise another DataTables on the modal that the 'Manage' button should open up. When it does open it should initialise another DataTables and get data from the AJAX request but in  my network tab in Chrome developer tools it isn't being ran.

***I have discovered the problem is, the DataTables isn't being initialized for some reason? the jQuery works up to there
I can't understand what I'm doing wrong here?***

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('.valid-tags').on('click', '.manageAutofixes', function(){
          $('.autofixes-modal').modal('show');
          $('.autofixes-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            var table = $('.autofixes-table').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                  "url": "/ajax/getValidTags.php",
                  "type": "POST",
                  "data": {
                    ruleID: ruleID,
                    type: 'autofixes'
                  },
                },
                "columnDefs": [{
                   "targets": 2,
                   "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                      return '<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm manageAutofixes" type="button">Manage</button> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteValid">Delete</button>';
                   }
                }],
                destroy: true     
            });         
          })    
      })


    });
```

**My modals HTML (included on the page)**

```
 <div class="modal fade autofixes-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="LargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-wide">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header modal-header-custom">
            <input class="ruleID" type="hidden"></input>     
                <button type="button" class="close destroyTable" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Autofixes</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="topBar">                       
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="autofix inputTextStyling">                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed autofixes-table" style="width:100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Autofix</th>
                            <th>Manage</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="autoFixesTable">
                    </tbody>                    
                </table>                           
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">                
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default destroyTable" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you load your modal from remote?

Comment: @Yuri The modal is in the same page, it is in its own file to keep the page clean.

Comment: You include it at load time or make an ajax request to fill the modal container?

Comment: @Yuri I've just included the first modals HTML

Answer (score 4):

To solve you buttons' problem, just use this kind of delegation:

```
$('#datatable').on('click', '.btn_class', function(){...});
```

It will match any click event occurring inside `#datatable` container on `.btn_class` elements, and it will solve your issue for dinamically added elements.

For what concerns Datatable inside your modal, I usually solve this by using a remote modal. That means that you put both your `<div class="modal-body">..</div>` html code and the relative JS code (that code to init the Datatable) on a (php) file, and load it with:

```
$("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
});
```

EDIT: Remember to use `$(document).ready();` in your remote php file too, so that code will run only when modal-body is fully loaded

Comment: Thanks Yuri, this fixed the buttons part. The only problem is that its opening one modal as it should but then one behind the modal with the buttons on, so it goes when the 'manage' button is clicked, it opens the correct modal, I close this modal, close the modal with the 'manage' buttons on and there is the 'correct' modal again?

Comment: I don't understand. It opens twice?

Comment: Okay the modal structure goes like this - Modal 1 , Modal 2, Modal 3.

When I click modal 1, modal 2 opens.
When I click modal 2 'manage', modal 3 opens.
When I close modal 3 and modal 2, another modal 3 is under them.

Comment: You have to keep only one `<div class="modal">...</div>` in your code, and load everything inside it, so give same `data-target="#myModal"` to all your buttons and just work with different `href` attr. By doing so, you are sure that you wont have more than one modal at a time

Comment: I am only using one modal.

Comment: I have just found out, I was including the modal twice, its fixed now thanks for your help Yuri.

Comment: You are welcome, please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem

Comment: It has only partially solved my problem, the other problem with the DataTables won't initialise.

Comment: Did you put JS code in remote file? Update your post

Comment: Yuri, the jQuery code above is how i'm initialising it and the HTML is my modal for it.

Comment: After the edits I suggested, the code should be a lot different, otherwise, it wont work for sure...

Comment: They both use the same type of datatable, the code is different with your changes in it.

Comment: You already have everything you need, just dig in it a little bit more ;)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by remote modal?

Comment: This just saved my butt here in 2022, Bootstrap 4.4 Modal in a datatable refusing to register the click event until I changed it to the delegation you recommended. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the buttons for the page 2 are loaded after you bind the action "click". You have to re-bind the action each time you load the results(by ajax)

you can use the datatable option `fnDrawCallback`

```
fnDrawCallback: function( oSettings ) {
  $('.manageAutofixes').on('click', function(){
      $('.autofixes-modal').modal('show');
      alert('hi');
  }
}
```